Display array of objects in an HTML table
I have this below array of objects as follows
const initState = [
    { id: 1, name: "bread", quantitiy: 50 },
    { id: 2, name: "milk", quantitiy: 20 },
    { id: 3, name: "water", quantitiy: 10 }
  ];

Below is the kind of generic html data that is expected from the above initState input.

So in order to achieve this table, i have made the code this way in a react component. (Note i am just displaying the jsx here for simplicity purpose)
return (
    <table>
      <tr key={"header"}>
        {Object.keys(state[0]).map((key) => (
          <th>{key}</th>
        ))}
      </tr>
      {state.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          {Object.values(item).map((val) => (
            <td>{val}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
    )

This works absolutely fine. I am getting stuck in a situation where in the table header names are inverted. for e.g. shown below. Please ignore the css width mismatch.

Basically, the id, name, quantity which was in the first row is now in the first column and all data display is reversed too. I tried finding online if there is anything with respect to showing data in this way but all i could find out was the one i implemented above.
Can someone please shed some light/ give insight on how to go about displaying data in this table. Should i message the initialstate variable in some way or should i change the jsx to display differently than the one implemented above. Any help is appreciated.

I don't know react and how the available online playgrounds work enough, to give you the direct react solution, but basically, you simply need to do it like this:
You loop over the keys of the first object first, because for each of those you will have to create a table row.
Then in that loop, you insert the current key into the first cell.
And then you loop over all the state objects, and output the value for the current key, to fill the rest of the cells for that row.


const state = [
    { id: 1, name: "bread", quantitiy: 50 },
    { id: 2, name: "milk", quantitiy: 20 },
    { id: 3, name: "water", quantitiy: 10 }
  ];
  
let html = '<table>';

Object.keys(state[0]).map((key) => {
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>'+key+'</td>';
    state.map((item) => {
        html += '<td>'+item[key]+'</td>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';
});
html += '</table>';

document.body.innerHTML = html;



I'm assuming to convert this into the necessary react/jsx syntax, shouldn't be too much of a challenge for anyone familiar with the syntax.

this is more than helpful. i would use it and do the necessary changes for react/ js syntax. thanks
